# In the IntelliJ IDEA, how can I use the IDE to show me a base class definition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for the first time and having a problem.  Here's an example of what I see when I look at the word Collection on line 80:

[image]

I want to learn more about `Collection`. But when I try to check where a class is declared by doing that menu action it comes up with nothing at all.  Also when I hover over Collection on the first line it shows nothing.

Is there something I need to do to make the IDE help me when I want to go to classes?

Comment: you mean like holding CTRL and clicking on the type in the code?

Comment: When I do that it comes up with a message box saying "Cannot find declaration to go to"

Comment: is your source folder correctly marked as a source root?

Comment: I am not sure about that.  I will look into it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` is an interface belonging to the JDK. If you want to associate documentation to it, you have to:

1) Go to `File -> Project Structure... -> SDKs`

2) Select the JDK you are using in your project

3) Select `Documentation Paths`

4) Add the JDK Javadoc either from the file system or from a remote location such as `https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/`.